# Airflow PostgresOperator only finds SQL file in the same folder as the DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I am only able to run a SQL file if I place it in the same folder as the DAG:

```
create_tables = PostgresOperator(
task_id="create_tables",
dag=dag,
postgres_conn_id="redshift",
sql="create_tables.sql"
)
```

If the create_tables.sql is in a different folder (parent folder, sibling folder) PostgresOperator throws `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound`, I have tried absolute path, relative paths (../create_tables.sql) but no luck.

How can I understand the file loading mechanism of this operator?

Comment: Hi Beppe. There's no need to sign your posts here. It is generally thought that the profile card is a sufficient show of authorship, and it does not need to be duplicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When defining the dag you have to add as argument template_searchpath, which is an absolute path of the folder. Then you just have to call the name of the file. Example:

```
with DAG('retraining_sagemaker',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval = timedelta(days=21),
         template_searchpath = ['/home/ubuntu/airflow_ci/current/scripts/antifraud']
         ) as dag:


    start = DummyOperator(
            task_id = 'start')

    generate_train_and_test_tables = PostgresOperator(
        task_id = 'generate_train_and_test_tables',
        sql = ['generate_train_and_test_tables.sql'],
        postgres_conn_id = 'redshift',
        autocommit = True)
```